# Automatically Create UML diagrams from Visual Studio 2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, uml

Is there any **tool\Software** that make automatically **UML diagrams** from an existing **visual studio 2008** project (C#).

(Tools work with Visual Studio 2010 also appreciated.)

*UML Diagrams may be all types eg, object, class, domain, collaboration, componant, state, deployment etc and test cases etc

I currently used .net framework 3.5.
I have Visual studio 2008 professional.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a Reflector .NET add-in that generates sequence diagrams, although it's never worked for me...

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio, you can create a Class Diagram model, which gets you started in the direction of a UML diagram.

If gives you the Properties, Behaviors, and Inheritance and Composition chains between types.

Here's an [article](http://www.developingfor.net/visual-studio/visual-studio-2008-class-diagram.html) about how to create them.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 Architecture Edition is supposedly going to have some pretty decent UML support.  I looked at it in Beta 1, but just pulled down the Professional version of Beta 2.

Some more information is available from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385832%28VS.100%29.aspx#DesignApplication).

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but there is no Architecture Edition in 2010, and only Ultimate Edition will have UML support

Comment: They officially changed the name since Beta 1, but it is the same concept.  It is now "Architecture Explorer", I believe.  The overbranding with 2010 is my only problem with it, so far.  ;-)

Comment: I'm basing my comment on this link, which describes the editions: http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2009/10/visual-studio-2010-simplified-to-four-skus-beta-2-arrives.ars

Answer (score 1):

You can create UML class, sequence, component, use case, and activity diagrams in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. You can link these diagrams to Team Foundation work items so you can plan and track development and test work. You can also create sequence, dependency graphs, and layer diagrams from code and use Architecture Explorer to browse and explore your solution.

I've posted more links on [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/275715/esther-fan) for more info.

Comment: @Esther: welcome to SO. There's a preference here to use full links. Some people won't click a short link, since they can't tell where it will lead them. I've edited your answer to include full links.